# How do you say 'turnabout' in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I can't find a translation for 'turnabout' in the standard Esperanto sources, and Google Translate throws up its hands at it.

There are two possible meanings to this, one is "to turn around" and another is the more idiomatic expression of turning the tables on a situation, for example in the phrase "turnabout is fair play". See [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turnabout%20is%20fair%20play) for this expression.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to clarify what the English word means because I don’t think it’s very common and it has a few different meanings in Wiktionary. If you just want the sense of “to turn around” maybe _returniĝi_ would work?

Comment: That's what I was going to go with.

Comment: Can you please give more context? The translation will depend heavily on what surrounds it.

Comment: Do you mean [roundabout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundabout)?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe: No, I didn't.

Comment: Aperis nova artikolo en Vikipedio: https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnabout_Intruder en kiu montriĝas alia signifo de "Turnabout", nome "konvertiĝa" bazita en la filmo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnabout_(film)

Answer (score 1):

Google Translate is not a good source to check. I would recommend the [annotated dictionary](http://esperanto-me.org/dic/) at esperanto.me. For "Turn about is fair play" it lists *ĉiu laŭ sia vico.* For other meanings of "turnabout", I would suggest using a thesaurus and checking those words in the annotated dictionary.

http://www.esperanto-me.org/dic/index.php?english=!turn+about+is+fair+play

Comment: How is that annotated dictionary not in violation of copyright?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment saying that the intended meaning is “to turn around”, I suggest *returniĝi*. It appears in PIV with the following definition:

> **returniĝi**. turni sin en kontraŭa direkto

And here is an example of it being used in this sense from the book *Marta*:

> Tion dirante, li leviĝis kaj kun etenditaj brakoj rigardis la forirantan virinon.
>
> — Fratino! — li ekkriis ankoraŭ unu fojon, — Mario! ha, ne forlasu min!
>
> Mario ne **returniĝis** kaj estis jam apud la pordo de la antaŭĉambro.